# How to put multiple integer values into a void array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to send some integers over a C socket, but I need to put all of them into a byte array first. How would I do that?

I was trying to do it like this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

void *arr;

arr+0 = (void *)&a;
arr+4 = (void *)&b;
```

But I got the following error:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: You want to put your values in a byte array, yet you are using a "void array" - why?

Comment: First [allocate memory for arr](http://man.cx/malloc), then you can use `*((int*)arr) = a; *(((int*)arr)+1) = b; `

Comment: btw, what you have is void pointer & not array. They are different.

Comment: I suggest learning the C language before trying to code in it.

Answer (score 2):

It seem that you don't know pointer arithmetic and memory allocation in C. First you need to allocate memory for `arr`

```
int **arr = malloc(sizeof(int*)*2)
```

and then

```
arr[0] = &a;
arr[1] = &b;
```

Comment: _Guessing_ OP's requirement, it should be `arr=a` not `arr=&a`.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need an array of bytes, then you should define it as such:

```
byte arr[8];
```

If you need to allocate memory dynamically, then use `malloc()` as proposed by @haccks.

In order to assign an integer to a fraction of your byte array, you have to take the address of that fraction by `&arr[n]` and then cast the result to and integer pointer. If you dereference that point, you can assign the value:

```
*(int*)&arr[0] = a;
*(int*)&arr[4] = b;
```

To retrieve the integer values from the array again, you have to basically do the same:

```
printf("a: %d\n", *(int*)&arr[0]);
printf("b: %d\n", *(int*)&arr[4]);
```

If you want to see what happens to your integer value on the byte level, then have a look at the following output:

```
printf("a0: %d\n", arr[0]);
printf("a1: %d\n", arr[1]);
printf("a2: %d\n", arr[2]);
printf("a3: %d\n", arr[3]);
```